# Writing a dynamic Linux device driver to access the com port

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I wish to write a Linux device driver which spawns a thread which listens to the comport on /dev/ttyAMA0. 
On the comport is an rf device which connects to a host of other devices. I wish I add each rf device as I discover them as if they were physical devices to Linux and upon probing the parameters of each device add files for controlling the device parameters.
I have done quite a bit of searching around this and have already done many of the simple hello world driver tutorials and found how to spawn threads from within a driver. 
I already know how to read/write to the comport from user-land c.

My question is; is this approach OK? i.e. a driver which can spawn multiple devices. Should this instead be a service? How about reading/writing to the comport from another device is this ok? What are the best practices? Examples?

N.B. I realise I will have to control access to the comport. I am choosing to ignore that complexity for the moment, but I will achieve this via some sort of semaphore.
This is for a personal project by day I'm mainly a c# developer.

**EDIT**
I have found this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036661/linux-device-driver-for-a-rs232-device-in-embedded-system?rq=1), I don't however believe it to be a duplicate. I think recommends not to write drivers over drivers. But I wish to add these external devices as if they were physical devices.

Comment: IIUC what you want is very similar to how pty pairs are spawned. In that case the origin is a network deamon, but it could just as well be a process sitting on a serial line.

Comment: Any chance you can point me at some code I can take a look at because I'm not sure what I'm googling for :)?

Comment: Well: the source for telnetd / sshd and maybe the manpages (or even the source) for openpty / forkpty ?

Comment: OK looked at this as the simplest example https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/busybox/blob/master/networking/telnetd.c it creates pty's as you said. I wish to create a device and files with function callbacks when they are read written to. Can I create devices & dev files from userland? Any example code?